# Path issue when developing locally - /web/ folder

Tags: siteurl

I'm building a Craft site locally and I'm unsure how to handle a path issue that will occur when the site goes live.

My understanding is that in a live implementation, the /web/ folder will become the root folder.  In twig templates, I can exclude /web/ from paths by using {{ siteURL }}, i.e. {{ siteURL }}images/.

However, you can't use Twig when adding page content through Redactor.  So if I want to include an image with the page text, I have to use "/web/" in the path.  When the site goes live, those paths will be broken since the /web/ folder will become the root.

How can I resolve this without having to change all the links to remove /web/ once the site is live? I feel like there must be a configuration file or setting somewhere I can change, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: How do you develop locally? 

Normally you also have a webserver (e.g. MAMP Pro or some Vagrant or the hot new Nitro thing) running locally which is using the /web/ folder as docRoot. So it should behave exactly the same way as on the live system.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't even thinking about it being an issue with the webserver settings, I was thinking it was a configuration issue somewhere in Craft. I set the wrong root directory when I created the virtual host in MAMP. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `@web` alias and the pass output of redactor field through `{{alias()}}` function? Thanks to that, `@web` will be always resolved as root url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that for future use. I ended up solving this issue by editing my .env file and removing "web" from the site root path. This was my first Craft site so I didn't understand at the time I set it up that the /web/ folder should be the root, not the project folder.